# NGINX try_files does not accept file name. It forcefully tries to open $uri no matter what I do

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to optimize a server. Long story short, the server gets queries like following:

*"https://my_domain_here.com/media/test.jpg?width=150&crop=center,center"* when it gets this request ti should return file "*/app/processed/test.jpg_w150_h0_cFalse_vcenter_lcenter.jpeg*"

I have the following section in my nginx.conf file:

```
    location ~* ^\/media\/(.*\.jpe?g)$ {
        root /app/processed/;
        set $filestr $1;
        if ( $arg_width ) {
            set $fullstr "${filestr}_w${arg_width}_h0_cFalse_vcenter_lcenter.jpeg";
        }

         # return 200 /$fullstr; <---- This returns the file name "/test.jpg_w150_h0_cFalse_vcenter_lcenter.jpeg"
        try_files /$fullstr @djangoapp;
    }
```

Now, I tested this million times. When i return "$fullstr", I get what I want which is "/test.jpg_w150_h0_cFalse_vcenter_lcenter.jpeg"

On the other hand, try_files return 404. There are two problems with this.

- 1 The file exists so it should be returning the file.
- 2 Even if we assume that the file is missing, should it not call djangoapp?

I enabled debugging and this is what I see in the logs:

```
Aug 15 15:30:54 localhost docker[1854]: 2021/08/15 15:30:54 [error] 9#9: *1 open() "**/app/processed/media/test.jpg**" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 222.222.222.222, server: ~^my_domain_here.com$, request: "GET /media/test.jpg?width=150&crop=center,center HTTP/2.0", host: "my_domain_here.com"
```

As you can see, i set the root to **"/app/processed/"** then I called **try_files** with **"$fullstr"** which is "/test.jpg_w150_h0_cFalse_vcenter_lcenter.jpeg". Even after all of this, try_files is trying to read the $uri from the given root path.

I have been pulling my hair for the last 4 hours. Can someone please point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See ["If is Evil... when used in location context"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: Removing the "if" fixed it... Wow, thanks a lot!